# ComponentDidUpdate re-renders again and again

Tags: react-native

I want to update the mapBox when user signup through the social logins in side drawer. For that , i have used componentDidUpdate() but is being called over and over again that causes the app to run very slow. Please suggest something to update the Map according to the loggedInUser through drawer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OEai.jpg)

```
   componentDidUpdate = async (prevProps, prevState) => {
        if (prevProps !== this.props) {
            const getData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth');
            const getParsedItem = JSON.parse(getData);
            const getCache = await this.retrieveCacheData('location');
            const parseList = JSON.parse(getCache);
            if (parseList) {
                const filterList = parseList.filter(e 
                         => e.uid === getParsedItem.userId)
                if (filterList.length > 0) {
                    this.setState({
                        listingData: filterList,
                        loader: false
                    })
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        listingData: [],
                        loader: false
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `componentDidUpdate` you should compare `prevState or prevProps` with `state or props` respectively. In a functional component this is equivalent to the `useEffect` hook. I personally prefer the `useEffect` hook. You can read more here [React Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) or this article [How to use componentDidUpdate in React by Cesare Ferrari](https://dev.to/cesareferrari/how-to-use-componentdidupdate-in-react-30en)

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(prevState !== this.state.something){
        console.log('state has changed')
    }
}


Functional component

useEffect(() => {

    /* write your return statement here */

}, [dependencies])
```

Comment: hi ! Thank you , i tried this and it keeps running when i click on anywhere on the screen.

Comment: Please add your code to the post. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the post , please have a look